# Flask-sqlAlchemy - Getting a type error for unexpected keyword 'cls' but this isn't called in my model view

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

So I am trying to create a User class which has a relationship with trainee & trainer class. I haven't got a clue what I'm doing so don't really know how to go about debugging this.

Here is my models.py

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from datetime import datetime
from enum import Enum

db = SQLAlchemy()

class UserRole(str, Enum):
    trainer = 'trainer'
    trainee = 'trainee'

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    age = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=True)
    city = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=True)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=True)
    weight = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=True)
    height = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=True)
    paypal_link = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=True)
    gender = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=True)
    user_role = db.Column(db.Enum(UserRole), nullable=False)
    

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.first_name

    def serialize(self):
        trainer = Trainer.query.filter_by(user_id = self.id).first()
        serializedTrainer = trainer.serialize() if trainer else None
        activity_per_trainer = ActivityPerTrainer.query.filter_by(trainer_id = serializedTrainer["id"]) if serializedTrainer else []
        
        trainee = Trainee.query.filter_by(user_id=self.id).first()
        bookings = Booking.query.filter_by(trainee_id=trainee.id).all() if trainee else []

        return {
            "id": self.id,
            "first_name": self.first_name,
            "last_name": self.last_name,
            "email": self.email,
            "age": self.age,
            "city": self.city,
            "weight": self.weight,
            "height": self.height,
            "gender": self.gender,
            "paypal_link": self.paypal_link,
            "user_role": self.user_role,
            "activities": [activity.activity.serialize() for activity in activity_per_trainer],
            "trainee": trainee.serialize() if trainee else None,
            "bookings": [booking.serialize() for booking in bookings] if trainee else []
        }
class Trainer(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    approved = db.Column(db.Boolean(), nullable=True)
    about = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=True)
    experience_level = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=True)
    bank_account = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=True)
    city = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=True)
    specialty = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=True)
    coaching_style = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=True)

    user = db.relationship('User', backref='trainer', lazy=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)

    activities = db.relationship('ActivityPerTrainer', lazy=True)

    def serialize(self):
        return {
            "id": self.id,
            "approved": self.approved,
            "about": self.about,
            "experience_level": self.experience_level,
            "city": self.city,
            "bank_account": self.bank_account,
            "specialty": self.specialty,
            "coaching_style": self.coaching_style,
            "user_id": self.user_id,
            "activities": [activity.serialize() for activity in self.activities]
        }

class Trainee(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    body_type = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=True)
    goal = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=True)
    fitness_experience = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=True)
    city = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=True)

    user = db.relationship('User', backref='trainee', lazy=True) #ENUM !!! 
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)

    bookings = db.relationship('Booking', backref='trainee', lazy=True)


    def serialize(self):
        return {
            "id": self.id,
            "body_type": self.body_type,
            "goal": self.goal,
            "fitness_experience": self.fitness_experience,
            "city": self.city,
            "user_id": self.user_id
        }
```

Here is my traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspace/Mi-PT-1/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2551, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/workspace/Mi-PT-1/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2531, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/workspace/Mi-PT-1/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 165, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "/workspace/Mi-PT-1/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2528, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/workspace/Mi-PT-1/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1825, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/workspace/Mi-PT-1/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 165, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "/workspace/Mi-PT-1/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1823, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/workspace/Mi-PT-1/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "/workspace/Mi-PT-1/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_admin/base.py", line 69, in inner
    return self._run_view(f, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/workspace/Mi-PT-1/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_admin/base.py", line 371, in _run_view
    return fn(cls=self, **kwargs)
TypeError: BaseModelView.create_view() got an unexpected keyword argument 'cls'
```

tried to lose the trainee class and make all users a trainee and pass userRole none & trainer

Comment: this is related to relationship, check that out

Comment: I ran into a similar issue on an object with a relationship. In the versions that I'm running, the last call of `fn(cls=self, **kwargs)` is in an except TypeError block, and the thing that led it there was an exception from `return fn(self, *args, **kwargs)` that was giving an exception that __str__ was returning None type instead of string. After fixing that in the __str__ implementation of my model, everything worked again. Hope that helps!